# Affinity Desginer: Diagonal Guides

Tags: affinity-designer, guides

How can one define diagonal lines on Affinity Designer?

I can't find a way to rotate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no tilted nor curved guides in Affinity Designer. But that's no problem. Draw ordinary lines or curves for that purpose and group them.

It's a good idea to rotate horizontal lines to get the tilted ones. This saves their tilting angles. It can be red from the transform panel. Copying it from there is an easy way to rotate something the same amount. Rotating objects doesn't snap reliably in Affinity D.

Rename the group in the layers panel for ex. to "My Guides". If you have snap to object geometry ON you can use those lines as guides. Lock the group to be sure they stay intact. Turn the group invisible when you want to see the image without the guides.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonal guides are not yet a thing in Affinity designer but you can you a custom grid with custom angles and make your graphics snap to grid:

[image: Affinity Designer custom grid angles]