# affinity designer iPad isometric grid snapping issue

Tags: affinity-designer, snapping, isometric

I’m a newbie to affinity and one of the main reasons I got affinity for was its isometric capabilities. Maybe it’s my OCD but my main issue is that shapes and path nodes don’t snap exactly to the isometric grid. They always snap a little off.

I have snapping enabled, the grid is turned on and the only layer I have is the shape layer that I am trying to build.

Am I missing an option in the snapping settings or is this something else?

Comment: @user287001 I have the grid turned on. And the only layer I have is the isometric shape layer that I am trying to build.

Comment: I removed my comment and edited the question.  The problem can be found in an old Affinity user forum discussion. https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/62076-no-snapping-to-grid/&tab=comments#comment-341856 I guess this is not operating error but a bug and it belongs to Serif's support, not to GDSE, no matter is it a bug or operating error.

Comment: @user287001 thanks for finding this link for me. So now I am really hesitant to working with isometric on the iPad now. Every time I watch a tutorial I always think about how misaligned everything is.

Comment: If snap to object geometry works ok you can very easily make your own grid and lock it. But it's a pain to use because snap takes half a second to get activated. Try Vectornator instead. No idea does it have the wanted capabilities, but it's free.

Comment: @user287001 so I can use lines to make my own grid and turn them into guides? That's what I did in illustrator to get precise isometric alignment

Comment: You must use your lines as guides, Affinity D has only horizontal and vertical guides. The problem is old. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138116/affinity-desginer-diagonal-guides I must say that I have only Affinity D for Windows.

Comment: @user287001 does it precisely snap to the isometric grid on windows? And what does snap to object geometry exactly do?

Comment: Win version seems to have perfect grid snaps, no visible error with biggest zoom. Snap to geometry = the Pen snaps to lines near enough, it snaps to a crossing if there's two crossing lines near enough. Snap takes half a second to get activated which is annoying.